# Probability Theory – Interesting Theoretical Task!!

Tags: probability, probability-theory, proof-writing, random-variables, characteristic-functions

Let $X$ be a random variable with characteristic function $\varphi_X(y)$ such that $\varphi_X(y) = 1 - o(|y|^{\alpha})$ for $y \rightarrow 0$. Prove that $P(|X| \geq t) = o(t^{-\alpha})$ for $t \rightarrow \infty$.

I think I need to use Markov's inequity, but I don't know how...

$$P(|X| \geq t) \leq \frac {E|X|} {t} \, \text{for} \, E|X| < \infty$$
But we don't know $E|X| < \infty$ or $E|X| = \infty$. And even if $<$, we don't know what $E|X|$ equals to. Or know? Can we find characteristic function for modulus X if we have it for just X?

Please, explain me this task.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This follows easily from the following well known inequality which you can find on page171 of Breiman's book: $P(|X|> t) \leq \alpha t \int_0^{1/t} [1-\Re \phi_X(s)] ds$. [I have replaced $u$ in that inequality by $\frac 1 t$]. Here $\alpha$ is a universal constant belonging to $(0,\infty)$.

Comment: ℜ – what does it mean? And how is this inequality meant in other books and articles? I want to understand it totally

Comment: @MrWhite I used $\Re z$ for the real part of the complex number $z$.

Comment: thank you very much! Your help is very useful!